# Selecting a subset matrix on basis of another ranked matrix for feature selection

Tags: matlab

I have two matrices.

```
     a   <120 x 6192>

 ranked  <1 x 6192>
```

The ranked matrix contains the rank of columns of matrix `a` ,i.e,  ranked from 1 to 6192.

I wish to select the top `n` from `a` to make a matrix `b` of of dimensions `<120 x n>`.
I am basically selecting top n features in matlab ,i.e.,

> n rows with the least rank.

Comment: The first `n` rows or the `n` rows with the largest rank?

Comment: `n` rows with the least rank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the job:

```
[~,idx] = sort(ranked);
topNColumns = a(:,idx(1:n));
```